# What would you call a Mode that is both a limited Demo but also gives you a fast overview of the program?

Tags: terminology

We are considering a mode for our program that accomplishes two different Outcomes with one set of functinonality:

This is educational software.

1. If they do not want to give an email address they are limited to 2 exercises (items) per lesson. We call this Demo mode.
2. If they are eligible for more lessons (signed up for a 1 week trial or subscribed) they can choose to be in Rapid Mode (which is essentially Demo mode) so that they can quickly find the right level for them.

I'd like to call both of theses these the same thing to avoid feedback like:

You re in Demo mode which supports only Rapid Mode.

I'd rather call it something like Rapid Review Mode and then if they uncheck it it gives them a choice of:

- Continue with Rapid Mode
- Sign up for a free trial
- Subscribe

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Separating the two, DEMO MODE seems to be a state of the account, often worded as "subscription level" "account level" or something like that.

Rapid Mode seems to be less of a "mode" and more of an action, that is a result of your account being "DEMO LEVEL" - so less "you're in rapid mode", and more "Complete your Rapid Review!"

You could do something like:

"Your Demo Account only allows you to access our Rapid Review."
x Continue with Rapid Review
x Sign up for free trial (and access more content)
x Subscribe

Feel free to tell me if I'm off base - but this could be a simple way to separate the account level and the content that the account level allows you to view.

Comment: That's a good way of phrasing it.